# Android - DialogFragment Doesn't Display The Entering Animation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am using the navigation component to navigate to "DeathDialogFragment" and I want it to display my entering animation.

But not only the XML UI width and height attributes are completely ignored therefore I had to do some workaround on onResume which caused the unintentional black box behind the dialog you will see down below (thanks to Android SDK) **but also the animation doesn't happen at all.**
It just gets displayed as a normal alert dialog.

I have tried initializing it without the nav component by adding my entering animation dialog theme to the styles.xml and implementing it in the dialog's code.
When that didn't work I override the onViewCreated instead of onDialogCreated and still no change in results.

Does anyone have any idea why animation does not work or how to remove the unintentional background black box?

***Dialog Screenshot (it pops up like this without displaying the animation)***
[image: SS]

***Navigation Component:***

[image: Navigation Component]

***DeathDialogFragment***

```
class DeathDialogFragment : DaggerDialogFragment()
{

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog
    {

        return if (activity != null && context != null)
        {
            val view: View = requireActivity().layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_death, ConstraintLayout(requireActivity()), false)
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            dialog.setView(view)
            dialog.create()
        }
        else
        {
            Timber.e("getContext() returned NULL, cannot return the Dialog")
            super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume()
    {
        super.onResume()
        val window = dialog!!.window ?: return
        val params = window.attributes
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        window.attributes = params
    }

}
```

***Navigation to DeathDialogFragment from GameDialogFragment***

```
Navigation.findNavController(binding.root).navigate(GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToDeathDialogFragment(score))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Returning a normal dialog instead of an alert dialog has solved the    issue:**

*DeathDialogFragment's onCreateDialog*

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog
        {
           
         val dialog = Dialog(requireContext(), R.style.Dialog)
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_fragment_death)
         dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.play_again_btn).setOnClickListener 
            {
                (requireArguments().get("PlayAgainListener") as PlayAgainListener).playAgain()
            }
         dialog.create()

         return dialog
        }
```

- **Removing and size and margin modification from the outer layout of the dialog layout has solved the unintended background box issue.**

  Instead of adding the margins to the outer layout, add them to the views which will make the same effect when you modify your window height and width attributes to WRAP_CONTENT on onResume:

DeathDialogFragment's onResume:

```
override fun onResume()
{
    super.onResume()
    val window = dialog!!.window ?: return
    val params = window.attributes
    params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    window.attributes = params
}
```

(The dialog_fragment_death has the custom Dialog style that I have created which had margins that were not shared in the question)